# Python - How to convert a string to an int by using the string 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example of what I would want to do:

```
x = 123
TYPE_TO_CONVERT_TO = 'int'

intx = convert(x, TYPE_TO_CONVERT_TO)
```

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried?

Comment: why not   int("3434")

Comment: `if TYPE_TO_CONVERT_TO == 'int': return int(x)` ? (assuming you'll implement other types as well).

Comment: improved TYPES = { t.name : t for t in [int, bool, basestring, float]}; def convert(x, t): return TYPES(t)(x)

Answer (score 5):

The type `int` (and other built-in objects) are in a special namespace (module), which you can access using `import builtins`. Thus you can do:

```
intx = getattr(builtins, TYPE_TO_CONVERT_TO)(x)
```

If you wish to also support types that might be defined in the current module, you can use:

```
intx = (globals().get(TYPE_TO_CONVERT_TO) or getattr(builtins, TYPE_TO_CONVERT_TO))(x)
```

The `builtins` module is also available using `__builtins__`, but this is an implementation detail. As Aran-Fey points out in a comment, `import builtins` is the right way to get a reference.

Comment: Thank you!  Kept googling for this info and could not find it!  I will try this out! :)

Comment: `__builtins__` is an implementation detail though. Better use `import builtins`.

Comment: Interesting; did not know that.

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure if the *existence* of the `__builtins__` variable is an implementation detail, but it *is* an implementation detail that `__main__.__builtins__` is a module object while `any_other_module.__builtins__` is a dict. So better not touch it if you don't have to.

Comment: Hmm, it's correct but it's pretty ugly.  I think more readable and robust is just to have a whitelist of names/types, like `{'int': int, 'float', float}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
t = eval(TYPE_TO_CONVERT_TO)
t('123') # => 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the type by themselves as they include `__call__` in their implementation.

```
def func(x, typ):
    typ = eval(typ)
    return typ(x)

func('12', 'list')
>>> ['1', '2']

func(1, 'str')
>>> '1'
```

Comment: @wim fixed and verified.